# javafx fxml ComboBox Error

Tags: javafx, combobox, fxml

Im trying to add a String to a javafx comboBox but i keep getting the above error :/

```
no suitable method found for add(String)
method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#1)
method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to CAP#1)
   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

## CODE

```
room_id.getItems().add("Hello");
```

## FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.AutoMaven.ui.controller.ComboTestController">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="room_id" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="185.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="260.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

## UPDATE

After using a list, i get

incompatible types: String cannot be converted to CAP#1 
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable: 
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?

```
ObservableList<String> list=FXCollections.observableArrayList("1","2","3","4");

room_id.setItems(list);
```

Comment: try to compile your code in any other compiler !

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `room_id` in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declare the `room_id` field in your controller class as

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> room_id;
```

If you're using

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<?> room_id;
```

`room_id.getItems()` returns a `ObservableList<?>` i.e. a `ObservableList` with unknown element type and `String` cannot be assigned to this type.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the ComboBox elements type is not set so it's by defauld  "?".
like this :

```
ComboBox<?> room_id = new ComboBox<>();
```

so to force the fxml ComboBox to have String values you have to add something like this :

```
<ComboBox fx:id="cbo_Bacteriologie_Aesculine" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="105.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="string option" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

or set the observable list  from code like this :

[Java ComboBox .setItems (ObservableList < T > value)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/javafx.scene.control/ComboBox/Java_ComboBox_setItems_ObservableList_lt_T_gt_value_.htm)

Comment: yes , i know just add the FXCollections tags like shown in the answer , and try the same code again !

Comment: did you add the 
 <String fx:value="string option" /> ?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/javafx.scene.control/ComboBox/Java_ComboBox_setItems_ObservableList_lt_T_gt_value_.htm

Comment: Yes, i did. I still get the same error? what is cap#1?

Comment: When i use the other method i get, ObservableList<String> cannot be converted to ObservableList<CAP#1>